# My Fifth Riley Riddle Wants to Tell you Something

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Here is my fifth Riley Riddle. Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks!

> My prefix has been fired,
>
> My suffix is a metal,
>
> My infix is the 7th word in the title backwards,
>
> And altogether I'm a short message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is-

> Bulletin

Prefix-

> Bullet, fired from a gun

Infix-

> llet, reverse of tell

Suffix-

> Tin, a metal

Together-

> Bulletin is a short message, also goes with the title.